# How to explain/name the "Feeling gigantic" sensation?

Tags: consciousness

A bit similar to [this](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/q/10553/8788) question, I did experience, twice, something, that I would qualify of, *pretty weird*.

A feeling of being gigantic, it was very very disconcerting.

Like, you look around you and you feel like everything around is you is way way way large, like if yourself you were being a tiny ant.

Then again, you may experience that your body is a mere gigantic vessel in which you, tiny entity, would be trapped in.

I did also experience fear at that time, of moving, of things. Because they were so gigantic and could *"hurt"* me if they'd fall on me for instance, etc. It also induced me dizziness.

Ultimately it wear off after a while. I do not do drugs, nor consumed anything.

**My question is:** Does anyone else has experienced similar and what is it called like? (Finally, could someone explain it to me?)

A few searches online yielded poorly results.

I do suspect that fatigue was at play but I can't link both together for sure.

Comment: Well, well, well. Yes I personally issued the experience but the question was, in my intentions at least, not personal, in a broader interest. I'm just curious about that phenomena that I can't even name. I'm not seeking for help (to quote the closing reasons). :) Lastly, I will say that, similar (IMO) questions succeeded, so yeah… Not really sure what to do here so I will shrug it off. Thanks anyway!

Comment: you can definitely rewrite this question to be less focused on you and more about the experience, if you would like--those often meet with success.

Answer (score 1):

The unusual feeling you've described here could be the variation of so called dissociative experiences, when a person's perception of the surrounding world and himself is distorted and therefore could evoke intense fear (and visa-versa). Quite often it could be the result of traumatic events in the past, which are not dangerous for a person in the present, but can still trigger the state of derealisaton and dissociative sensations, including the feeling that the body has expanded. These "weird" sensations ones were chosen by the person's body and mind as the most effective defence mechanism in traumatic situation; however they subconsciously may occur in the present life even when there is no any obvious reason.

Stress only could also provoke the feeling of dissociation.

It is not necessary the answer to your case, because there is not enough information about your personal history and current events in your life; however if we take the description of the "feeling gigantic" separately, to my mind, it could be considered as the body dissociation experience.

Comment: This is definitely an interesting hypothesis, though it could be hard to be answered to as it also involves the possible implication of the subconscious.